# Check FIle Changes

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, signals

I'm programming in C in unix OS and I'm stuck in a problem.
I need to operate in some files selected by the user and check if some *token string* is in there, but it only makes sense if it checks the file when it is changed. So I thought to use a `SIGALARM` that every second checks the modification date of the file but it seems that it isn't "good".
Is there any other way to do it? OS has any tweak to use in order to become easier?

Thanks.

Comment: What Unix OS are you using ? Do you need a portable solution or one that works with your OS ?

Comment: Ubuntu only, windows or other aren't necessary I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, there is an API called inotify which will do what you want. For a more portable solution, look into the gio sublibrary of glib, specifically [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GFileMonitor.html). It might be able to do what you want but I am not completely certain.